# Implementation suggestions for kwarg aliases

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Some folks I'm working with have decided that they want the functions in a library we're working on to accept multiple names for the same arg.
<sub>(The motivation for this is that people using this library in an academic setting will find Unicode keyword-args intuitive, easy, and obviously-correct, while non-academics would find them totally unacceptable. Reasons why the whole idea might not be good are out-of-scope for this question.)</sub>

As an example:

```py
def lambda_squared(**kwargs):
    """
    @param λ: A kwarg, which will be squared.
    @param lambda: An alias for λ. Exactly one is required, don't use both.
    @return: λ**2
    @raise ValueError: Raised if no or both kwargs are passed.
    """
    keys = ('λ', 'lambda')
    try:
        key = next(k for k in keys if k in kwargs)
        assert 1 == len(kwargs)
    except:
        raise ValueError('Exactly one of `λ` or `lambda` is required as a kwarg.')
    return kwargs[key]**2
```

There are going to be a handful of args taken by a lot of different functions that will follow this pattern. A decorator seems like a good idea, here's one way that might look:

```
@alias_kwarg('lambda', as='λ')
def lambda_squared(*, λ):
    """
    @param λ: A kwarg, which will be squared.
    @return: λ**2
    """
    return λ**2
```

While I can certainly build such a decorator myself pretty quickly, the less of that we're doing the better. Does anyone know an off-the-shelf decorator (or similar)? Is there a "normal" way of implementing this?

Comment: While I also find lambda char much prettier than noisy `lambda`, I still wouldn't do it. Adds extra complexity with very little benefit. Would you do it though, I'd also go with the decorator as it leaves original function untouched. 

Some reasons why not: grepping becomes harder, as you need to grep multiple aliases. Some tools could also have issues with those, even though Python should be fine.

Comment: It seems cleaner to me to not accept `**kwargs` and to simply use something like `def foo(λ=None, lambda=None):` then explicitly check that only one is used, else throw an error. Just use a function, `def check_args(λ=None, lambda=None)`, a decorator seems like overkill. In any case, the answer to your question is "no, there is no off-the-shell decorator" for this, at least not in the standard library. I don't think this sort of thing is "normally" done, and where it is, the logic is just implemented